# Google Analytics API throwing 500 Internal Server Error (Backend Error)

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytic API to fetch data. I am fetching data from last 2 years without any issue. But, from yesterday, on server i am getting following error on API call : -

Google.GoogleApiRequestException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Backend Error [500] Errors [Message[Backend Error] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global] ]  ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Another noticeable thing is when i have got above error constantly on server upon calling API.
that time i have tried same API calls from my local machine - i have not got any error and able to download / fetch data without any issue from Google Analytic on my local machine.

I have also tried exponential backoff (delay) to call API on server. but, that help me up to only 5 to 10 calls. But after that i have got same errors. & same thing is working on my local machine.

Please,let me know if anyone has idea about this issue & how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What type of authorization are you using to make the call? Google may no longer support it or the way it's trying to authenticate.

Comment: I'm having the same problem: *some* requests return 500.

Comment: Same issue with Google Script/Spreadsheet. Most of the time it works but now and then we get random 500. These requests are re-tried and eventually succeed. So seems like an error on Google end.

Comment: Same issue here.Issue happening on my production but not on stage OR local why? I am using oauth 2.0 with secret p12 key.All things are same on all servers still having issue with production only